# How can i wrap label text in Highcharts Grouped Categories

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can i wrap my label text or increase the cell height to make it responsive? This is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wab6upvs).

[see the label overlapping here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2EP1.png)

html:

```
<div id="container" class="chart-container"></div>
```

jquery:

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: "container",
            type: "column",
            marginLeft: 85,
            marginRight: 15
        },
        title: {
            useHTML: true,
            x: 10,
            y: 80,
            text: ''
        },
        series: [{
            data: [4, 14, 18, 5, 6, 5, 14, 15, 18]
        }],
        xAxis: {
            style:{
                overflow: 'none',
                crop : false
            },
            min:0,
            opposite:true,
            labels: {
                style: {
                    textOverflow: 'none',
                    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                    color: '#000000',
                    fontSize: '11px',
                    overflow: 'none',
                    crop : false,
                },
                gridLineWidth: 1,
                groupedOptions: [ {
                        rotation: 0, // rotate labels for a 2nd-level
                        y:10,
                    }],
                rotation: -90 // 0-level options aren't changed, use them as always
            },
            categories: [{
                name: "Fruiqweqw ewqeqwet",
                categories: ["Appleasd asdadd", "Bananaasd asdsa", "Orange asdad"]
                }, {
                name: "Vegetableasdasd",
                categories: ["Carrot asd", "Potato sdf", "Tomato"]
                }, {
                name: "Fishqwewewqewq",
                categories: ["Codasdsa", "Salmonasd", "Tuna"]
            }]
        }
    });
});
```

The labels in the x axis are out of the given space. Is there any way i can do it with out fixing the width as i have lots of labels in my actual project?

Comment: Link to jsfiddle is not working.

Comment: please remove the ] in the end , i will  edit it

Comment: its working now

Answer (score 0):

ok I got it

```
style: {
          width: 10
        }
```

fixing the width will fix it 
check it here 
http://jsfiddle.net/q0kns5av/